# ¿Como ajustar tamaño de page en ventana WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Buenas es que tengo una ventana, y dentro de esa ventana tengo un FRAME

```
<Window x:Class="CDA.Views.PrincipalView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CDA.ViewModels"
        xmlns:class="clr-namespace:CDA.Clases"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CDA.Views"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        MinWidth="1300"
        SizeToContent="Height"
        Title="PrincipalView" Height="1080" Width="1920" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Icon="/CDA;component/Images/logo.png">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:PrincipalViewModel x:Key="PrincipalVM"/>
        <class:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource PrincipalVM}">

        <!-- .... -->
        <!-- Aca hay otro codigo no relevante -->
        <!-- ... -->

        <Frame x:Name="Frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Background="BlueViolet"/>
        <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Heigth="100">
            <TextBlock Text="Juan" />
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Y dentro de ese FRAME yo cargo una PAGE.xaml, la idea es que cargue la "Page" y debajo carge el textBlock, osea que el contenido de la pege se acomode a los diferentes tamaños de pantalla

**QUIERO QUE SE VEA ASI**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se vea con ese pie de pagina azul, y que sin importar el Height de la ventana que este ejecutando el programa se acomode el contenido de la Page que estoy instanciando

**PERO SE VE ASI CADA QUE LO EJECUTO, COMO QUE SE DEFASA EL TAMAÑO DE LA PAGE**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pierdo ese pie de pagina azul :( y no se como hacer que el programa tome automaticamente el alto y lo ajuste... que ajuste el contenido de la PAGE

El codigo de la page es este:

```
<Page x:Class="CDA.Views.HomePage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CDA.Views"
      xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
      TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
      TextElement.FontSize="13"
      TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
      TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
      FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
      d:DesignHeight="1080" d:DesignWidth="1920"
      Title="HomePage">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="Light" Padding="10" Height="115" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="..\Images\logo.png" Height="90"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Pagina Principal del programa" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Version 22.4.2020" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsCentered="True" />
            </DockPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="97*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,254" >
                <Image gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="..\Images\space.gif" Height="500px" Width="500px" Source="D:\Proyectos\WPF\CDA\CDA\CDA\Images\space.gif"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```